# Exporting to Swagger from Paw?

Tags: paw-app

Does anyone know if there exists a code generator for Paw which will export to Swagger definitions? I couldn't find one in the list of generators and was wondering how such a popular format could be left out.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's coming next week :D

We have been working hard on an API conversion tool, on which the Swagger exporter will be based (it's open source on GitHub: https://github.com/luckymarmot/API-Flow, but still not officially released).

Also, there's already a Swagger importer if that can help you: https://paw.cloud/extensions/SwaggerImporter